# manupulate selected option in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

here is my code and when i click the button to show the return from the function nothing appear.

HTML

```
<!doc type HTML>
<HTML>
<head>
<meta catharses="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<form name="form4"  method="post" action="">

<div align="center">

<p>
<select name="quantity" id="quantity" width: 129px;">
<option>3,000</option>
<option>5,000</option>
<option>10,000</option>
<option>20,000</option>
<option>50,000</option>
<option>100,000</option>
<option>200,000</option>
<option>300,000</option>
</select>
<br />
</p>
</div>
```

```
<scrip> text=JavaScript

var selected_quantity = function () {

if(form4.selectedIndex==0){
return  50;

}
if(form4.selectedIndex==1){

return  60;//and so on,,,
```

Comment: I think you missed to link the relevant JavaScript code.

Comment: it's normal. you didn't do anything to do anything.

Comment: Your form has a blank `action` and no button to submit anything. The `select` lets you choose a `quantity` but it doesn't do anything with it.

Comment: i think he is just very new, give him a break,@Amit Klein you need to post your javascript attempt here also.

Comment: which button and also add value="something" to your options.do some search first.

Comment: Your form needs to have a `submit` input type to get a button that actually sends the data somewhere.  It should look like this: `<input type="submit" value="Submit">`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the form to automatically submit when the user changes the dropdown box, add the 'onchange' attribute to the  tag, to trigger the forms submission. I believe you will also have to add an ID attribute to the form itself, too:

```
    <form id="form_main" name="form4"  method="post" action="<url to post results to>">
 <div align="center">
  <p>
   <select name="quantity" id="quantity" style="width: 129px;" onchange="form_main.submit();">
   <option value="3,000">3,000</option>
  <option value="5,000">5,000</option>
  <option value="10,000">10,000</option>
  <option value="20,000">20,000</option>
  <option value="50,000">50,000</option>
  <option value="100,000">100,000</option>
  <option value="200,000">200,000</option>
  <option value="300,000">300,000</option>
  </select>
</p>
</div>
 </form>
```

I hope this helps!